# Flutter animation is not smooth at first time render

Tags: flutter

Why buildTransition on screen navigation even Hero animation is never smooth at first run?

How to make a prefect smooth animation always?

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you test with release or profile build? Performance of debug builds isn't representative.

Comment: I run it directly on my phone.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question :D You need to build with `--release` or `--profile`. If you run from IDE you'll get a debug build by default which is unsuitable to measure any performance metrics or animations or build output size.

Comment: :D sorry forgive my newbie....yes true after looking how to run it on profile mode....the lag doesn't happen. Thanks a lot! What if you put it on an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to build with `--release` or `--profile`. If you run from IDE you'll get a `--debug` build by default, which is unsuitable to measure any performance metrics or animations or build output size.

```
flutter run --profile
```

More details in https://flutter.io/docs/testing/ui-performance

Comment: As in, if you have a little corner banner that says "debug", you're using the JITter compiler, and all bets about smoothness are off.

Answer (score 10):

This is a known issue in flutter where you have to "warm-up" the graphic api (SkSL) first. After a third run, usually it will become smooth.

The problem happens in both iOS an Android.

For iSO, the lag usually occurs in metal api as Apple has recently dropped support for OpenGL which is usually where the Skia graphic engine is implemented.

Work around and temporary solution are found on this page.

[Extreme jank on iOS/Android the first time any kind of animation or transition runs (release build) - skia shader compilation #61450](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61450)

## Update

Flutter has updated their official docs on this issue

[Reduce shader compilation jank on mobile](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/shader)